# PatternLayout double quote escape character in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I need a log in log4j2 as below:

14:28:00.404 app_name="splunk sample app" method_name=main desc="sample log"

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d app_name=\"%X{app_name}\" method_name=%M(%L) %m %n"/>
```

Pattern is failing because of double quotes. What is the escape character for double quate so the value of the key value pair is within double quotes in the log.

```
ThreadContext.put("app_name", "splunk sample app");
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your pattern, simply replace the two `\"` with `&quot;` (the XML entity for the `"` character):

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d app_name=&quot;%X{app_name}&quot; method_name=%M(%L) %m %n"/>
```

It will then log what you want:

```
14:28:00.404 app_name="splunk sample app" method_name=main desc="sample log"
```

Comment: Great. Feel free to mark this answer as useful if you think it is (gray arrow up at the left)

Answer (score 0):

Support for other special characters like \t for tabs is now being added (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-682).

This did not make it into Log4j-2.0-rc2, you'll need to build from trunk to use this if you want it before 2.0 is released.

Comment: ok, waiting for 2.0 release to use it in prod. Got some errors while building from trunk.

Comment: If you have problems with trunk you should tell the team so it can be fixed. 2.0 will be based on trunk... You are building with "mvn clean install"?

Comment: i'll try again. I just took the core alone to build. yes clean install.